# change 110v outlet to 240v/30 amp?

Tags: 240v

I need to install a 240v/30 amp outlet for a microwave (a Turbochef, kind of like a microwave on steroids.)  I have a single 110v outlet on its own circuit.  It's using 10 awg copper.  Can I replace that with a 240v outlet and change the breaker to a 30 amp 240v breaker?  The run is about 30 feet.  Basically my question is 10 awg appropriate for this application?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?  Also, does this Turbochef use a NEMA 6, a NEMA 10, or a NEMA 14 plug?

Comment: 30 feet of #10 wire is fine for a 30A circuit. But you *may* not have the required number of conductors, depending on the microwave oven. If it requires 4 wires (2 hots, a neutral and a grounding wire), then you can't use the grounding wire as a neutral. No neutral is required for the 240V circuit powering the microwave (it's 240V from "hot" to "hot"), but if the oven has internal 120V auxilliary circuits for things like the timer, a light or lights, a display, and so on, then it's probably designed to use a neutral wire (hot to neutral will be 120V).